# Developing/testing block styles in isolation in Webpack

Tags: css, webpack, sass, webpack-dev-server

Webpack is great for taking a single entry point and outputting an efficient bundle of dependencies. However I am struggling with the development workflow of Webpack especially when it comes to styling.

Like many front end devs I like to use precompiles like sass and stylus. I also like to break each block into seperate files. I have always been taught to style elements in isolation.

`Styles
  |
  |+-- button.scss
  |+-- search.scss
  |+-- logo.css
  |+-- etc...`

My question is, how do I test these individual block?

webpack-dev-server is great for live style compiling but if I want to test an individual block it seems I would have to have an individual webpack.config for every single block.

Comment: Can you give an example of a test for an individual block?

Comment: The test is to test the style in the browser. I am not talking about JS unit testing